# Unix user without password still needs password

Tags: bash, unix, osx-mavericks, sudo, dscl

I created a user on OS X Mavericks – `dscl . -create /Users/newuser UserShell /bin/sh` – without setting any password. This is confirmed by reading the user file with the dscl interactive prompt.

However, when I `sudo su newuser` and try to `su` back to root, bash prompts me for a password. I need to close the terminal and open a new window to exit the user session.

Why is that?

Comment: You can type "exit" or ctrl-d to exit the `su` shell.

Comment: This seems like a question better suited to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `sudo su newuser`, you are effectively running as "newuser". Running `su` as "newuser" will require escalating to root, requiring a password.

Try just exiting the the original `su` session with `exit` or `<ctrl-d>`. This should return you to the original shell.

Comment: But the root password is not being accepted, so what password is required?

Comment: Are you sure `root` has a password? As a security precaution, Mac OS X doesn't ship with one.